# gcc replacing default library search paths

Tags: linux, gcc, autotools, binutils

I want to make a "bare bones" Linux environment, so first I compile and install the Linux kernel to a directory called /distro (on the "host" machine).

After configuring the boot loader, I am able to boot into this kernel and it naturally pauses immediately as it cannot find /sbin/init to execute.

So then I want to run bash in this environment, so I attempt to compile bash and it works. However, the bash package depends on headers and libraries from the ncurses and readline packages. I haven't installed these packages into /distro, so the reason that the compilation succeeded is because it used the ncurses and readline from the host machine, which I do not want. In other words, I want the bash build process to actually fail because I have not installed ncurses and readline into /distro. I do not want the build process to use any packages in the host machine.

For include paths this is easy as I can do this:

```
./configure CFLAGS="-nostdinc -I/distro/usr/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.3/include"
```

The `-nostdinc` option tells GCC to not search in standard paths such as /usr/include and the like, and then I manually specify the include directory in /distro, and also a necessary directory that contains headers essential to GCC even though they are on the host machine.

However there doesn't appear to be a GCC option like -nostdinc for libraries. As far as I know, there are two ways to glean the default library search paths that GCC uses:

```
gcc -print-search-dirs | grep libraries
gcc --verbose a.c 2>&1 | grep LIBRARY_PATH
```

which apparently are not the same, but I'm assuming that `-print-search-dirs` is more complete.

As far as binutils ld is concerned, the `-T` option can be used to use a script file without any SEARCH_DIR entries.

So, the only way to replace the GCC default library search paths is to hack the sources and compile a custom GCC? There really should be some sort of option for this.

Comment: Finding and resolving those libraries and doing whatever linking is necessary is the responsibility of the system linker.  gcc simply delegates that work out to it.  See the ld documentation.

Comment: (Personally if I were doing this I'd build a toolchain, including binutils, in a chroot jail, just as if building a cross-compiler... too many little things will be different in your host compiler and staged environments...)

Comment: gcc actually adds library paths to ld (or collect2 which in turn calls ld, or however the case may be) via -L. I'm looking for a way to inhibit GCC from adding library paths via -L.

Comment: [unshare](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unshare) allows you to hide namespaces (including directories) whilst running a program. That is one possible way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do.   If the goal is to have bash run on the target system, build it statically, or build it dynamically and install the libraries on that system.  If you're trying to get gcc to be aware which libraries are on the target system, use gcc in a chroot.   If something else... then what?    You will break the binaries that are built if you generate object code that requires the linker to put relations in to build a binary, but you deny the linker access to those files.

Comment: You say you want the build to fail, but removing -L somehow is not supported and will cause /all/most/ builds to fail, not just those which depend on binaries not installed in your target...

Comment: "I really don't understand what you're trying to do." "I'm looking for a way to inhibit GCC from adding library paths via -L."